# Maven Assembly plugin dependency version scope

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin, parent-pom

I have a maven project using the assembly plugin which includes, amongst other things, the project dependencies.

One of the dependencies is declared in the pom as:
    

    `<dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.sqlj</groupId>
      <artifactId>runtime12</artifactId>
      <version>11.1.0.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>`

The pom for the project also has a parent pom, which must be included, but I cannot change.  In there, is:
    

    `<dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.sqlj</groupId>
      <artifactId>runtime12</artifactId>
      <version>10.1.0.2.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>`

The dependency declaration in the xml for the assembly plugin reads:
    
    `<dependencySets>
      <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>etc/lib</outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <!-- INCLUDE ALL DEPENDENCIES -->
        <includes></includes>
      </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>`

When the assembly stage is run, version 10.1.0.2.0 of the dependency is packaged, rather than 11.1.0.0.0, which I'd expect to override it, as it in fact does for the compile stage prior to the assembly.

Have I made an error here?  Or if not, is there any way I can force the assembly stage to prefer the dependacies declared in the child pom rather than the parent?  I've googled, but so far come up empty...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the correct way should be to change parent to use tag `dependencyManagement` instead of dependency and let child project use this dependency or set one another.

But apparently you can't change the parent.

So, you should change the `dependencySet` configuration of assembly descriptor. Use the tag `excludes` to exclude the unwanted artifact.

You can read the manual reference for assembly descriptor here:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html